# Making a movable and zoomable map

Tags: java, android, dictionary, zooming

I am making a simple game on android. I want to make a map that would be able to zoom, so the images on it have to disappear when they left the screen. I want to put an image for background and put other images on it. The problem is that the images don't "stick" to the map, so when i zoom the background the images are still in the same place of the screen. I was looking for the solution in the internet, but i didn't find anything. I am writing in Android Studio in java.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Perhaps with an illustration, and the code you've tried to use? It's difficult to understand what you're asking for.

Comment: I am trying to make a game map on which would be placed objects for example buildings. I made a map that I can zoom, but the objects placed on it are still on the same position on the screen. I want the objects to change position on the screen while I zoom the map. For example when I zoom the map 8 times, I want that objects being near any side of the map will be out of the map. The program that I got now make that objects are still on the same place on the screen while I zoom the map.